# Save stored procedure in string in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to call a stored procedure that will return only one record and save to a View Model.

Eg
Models

```
public class News {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string HeadLine { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class NewsCategory {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NewsCategor { get; set; }
}
```

View Models

```
public class VMNews {
    public List<News> TodayNews { get; set; }
    public NewsCategory NewsCat { get; set; }
}
```

Action Method

```
public ActionResult Index() {
     VMNews objnews = new VMNews();
    //This works fine as it contains List   
    objnews.TodayNews = db.Database.SqlQuery<News>("usp_News").ToList();
    //This gives a error stating Cannot implicitly convert type.....    
    objnews.NewsCat = db.Database.SqlQuery<NewsCategory>       ("usp_NewsCategory");
    return View(objnews);
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `FirstOrDefault()` method to take only one record.

Currently your stored procedure returns `collection` of `NewsCategory` and you are trying to assign a `collection` to a `single object` which will give `error` which you are getting.

```
objnews.NewsCat = db.Database.SqlQuery<NewsCategory>("usp_NewsCategory").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Yes its working and thanks because of your solution I learned a new think that First or Default also exists.